# What does "Invalid stack, only stack 1 and 5 are supported for builds" means?

Tags: wercker

I am trying to trigger a new Wercker build by hitting the API endpoint [mentioned in the documentation](http://devcenter.wercker.com/docs/api/endpoints/builds), but the API returns the following response:

```
{"statusCode"=>400, "error"=>"Bad Request", "message"=>"Invalid stack, only stack 1 and 5 are supported for builds"}
```

What does the error message *"Invalid stack, only stack 1 and 5 are supported for builds"* mean?

I tried to send the request using the following script:

```
$ jq . -c <<JSON | curl -s -d @- -H 'Authorization: Bearer token' -H 'Content-type: application/json' 'https://app.wercker.com/api/v3/builds' | jq .
{
  "applicationId": "applicationid",
  "branch":"develop",
  "envVars":[
    {"key":"HOGE_FOO","value":"true"}
  ]
}
JSON

{
  "statusCode": 400,
  "error": "Bad Request",
  "message": "Invalid stack, only stack 1 and 5 are supported for builds"
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your edits! @asymmetric

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Wercker employee here!]

The builds endpoint is for the Wercker classic stack, which had distinct notions of builds and deploys. The current Wercker Workflows stack uses the [runs API endpoint](http://devcenter.wercker.com/docs/api/endpoints/runs) to control arbitrary pipeline runs.

The error message you are seeing is telling you this in a somewhat cryptic way. Version 6 refers to the Workflows stack, 1 and 5 are classic/deprecated stacks. I'll make this more clear in our documentation, but if you replace your calls from the builds API endpoint to the Runs API endpoint, it should work!

Comment: Yes, as you have said, I'm using current Workflows stack.
I tried the `Runs API`, success to build. Thanks!